# Google Sheets Query Get Row When Any of These Cells are Not Empty

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

So like my title states I would like to select via a query only the rows where certain cells are not blank/empty.

I have 4 pools that I have a form for collecting their chemistry.  In separate sheets I would like to display each pool's data.

I'm expecting some incomplete submissions but if I get just one value I would still like to get it, however I don't want anywhere that pool values are completely empty.

This is the query that I thought might work however I only get the headers.
[This is the example sheet anyone can work on](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jh9CACdhxNvDBGIwMew0uZesD8UrkMJ7PwoCtxlvx40/edit?usp=sharing).

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A:N,"SELECT C,E,G,H WHERE G !='' OR H !='' ORDER BY C, E ASC", 1)
```

`ORDER BY` doesn't work either.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Please try:

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A:N,"SELECT C,E,G,H where G is not null or H is not null order by C,E")
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Didn't know about `is not null`

Comment: Just be aware that not null see a cell with a string as empty because with the not NULL command only cells with number values in them are not empty. Checking for emptiness with text strings: WHERE B != ''
Checking for emptiness with numerical strings: WHERE B is not NULL