# Using Google Sheets drop down menu to query only when an option is selected

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

So my little project is to make a "calculator" for a components list. Moving left to right, the drop downs narrow down what compatible parts are available by using a few query functions to narrow down the options. Issue is, I want to only query when a drop down is NOT blank as having blank spots is returning false answers.

Here is what I ahve at the moment.

```
=query({Player!A3:J}," select Col1 where Col4 = '"&C10&"' or Col5 = '"&C10&"' ")
```

I have tried doing "select Col where C10 is not null and...", ISBLANK(), and a few options but no success. Anything I am missing?

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets Query Get Row When Any of These Cells are Not Empty](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/72686/google-sheets-query-get-row-when-any-of-these-cells-are-not-empty)